# How to add a Google Maps containing GeoRss Feeds on a page - don't know exactly what module to use

Tags: 7, google-maps, javascript, location

I have developed a Google maps following the example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-georss but I am new to Drupal and I don't know how to include it on a page. Could someone please tell me what module should I use?

Some guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GMap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module. This module solve your issue.

[How to use ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5rTcz7EXEQ)

If your issues not solved then try to use any of these modules :

1. [Simple Google Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_gmap)
2. [Google Maps Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmaplocation)

For GeoRSS try to use below module :

1. [GeoRSS](https://www.drupal.org/project/georss)
2. [Google Maps Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmaps)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried the Gmap module right now, but the problem is that I can add locations but cannot add GeoRss feeds on the map.Maps Location Module also focuses on one location from what I understood. What else would you recommend?

Comment: check my updated answer. I hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that GeoRss and Google Maps Tools are not compatible with Drupal 7.x since only a version for 6.x is offered